# Highcharts tooltip overlapped by absolute positioned element

Tags: highcharts

For my chart, I would like to position an element absolutely on the chart but under the tooltip in terms of stacking, would this be possible?

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/0vdnrm26/1/,
The final tooltip on `Asia` is being overlapped by the `hello world` div, ideally the tooltip would be over the `hello world`.

Comment: You should update your question with more details and provide the code that you have as of now. This may give people more to work with you on.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening like this because absolute position of the div, it is nothing to do with highcharts. Highcharts charts are svg elements and are rendered after.

You can use [SVGRenderer#text](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text) to have same thing.

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Growth by Region'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Billions'
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value / 1000;
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' millions'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      lineColor: '#666666',
      lineWidth: 1,
      marker: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#666666'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Asia',
    data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
  }, {
    name: 'Africa',
    data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
  }, {
    name: 'Europe',
    data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
  }, {
    name: 'America',
    data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
  }, {
    name: 'Oceania',
    data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
  }]
}, function(chart) { // on complete
  var width = chart.chartWidth - 70;
  chart.renderer.text('Hello World', width, 50)
    .attr({
      //stroke: 'black',
    })
    .add();

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

/*.some-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  background: pink;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> </div>
  <!--<div class="some-div">
    hello world
  </div>-->
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sysy7t5o/) demo